# Constructing a deterministic one way infinite single tape Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

If I have an input string that is only composed of $a$'s and $b$'s, how can I construct a Turing machine that only accepts strings where the number of $b$'s divides the number of $a$'s?

For example:

$aaaabb$ is accepted

$baaab$ is rejected

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather reasonable way to implement this in Turing machines:

1. Sort the `b`s and the `a`s so that the input tape is composed of `b`s followed by `a`s.
2. Repeatedly perform the following operation: remove $B$ `a`s from the end of the input tape, where $B$ is the number of `b`s.
3. Accept if you never got stuck perform an iteration of the previous step.

The second step can be implemented without explicitly counting $B$. For the first step, you can implement the simplest algorithm you can think of, say bubble sort.

Comment: Within the limitations of a TM, I've found that gnome sort is easier to implement.